# How do I connect to a SQL Server 2008 instance on my network?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 SQL instances in 2 virtual machines. I'm able to see the other instance in one machine but I cant connect to it.

Probably some permission problem...but I don't know where to look.

Can someone help me?

*edit*:
the first problem was in fact not having TCP/IP enabled, solved that and the error changed now I have error 18452. (I'm trying to connect with windows authentication, also tried with sql authentication in that case I get error 18456)

Both SQL instances are default

*edit2*:
After changing the autentication to windows and SQL, I can login in one of the instances using sql autentication (user SA), on the other...it gives me error 18470, but everything looks ok with that login (at least for me... maybe one of you can tell me were should I look)

*edit3*:
After enabling login sa everything works as expected in SQL authentication mode.

I change my question to, what if I wanted windows authentication mode? how could I do it?

Comment: What message do you get when you try to connect? How are you trying to connect? Do you have TCP/IP protocol enabled for that instance?

Comment: We've noticed that your questions seem to lack a bit of detail. We are more than happy to help you, but you're going to have to help us help you. May I suggest the comments in http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask (especially those in the sidebar of that question!) and just the consideration that if we're going to help, we'll definitely need lots of information from you.

Comment: @ShawnMelton that was part of the problem, solve it now.
I've added some extra info in my post now

Comment: Windows authentication would just require a Windows account be added to the instance and given permissions. Adding an Windows account would have been an option during the install wizard.

Comment: @ShawnMelton can I add it now? (if yes how?)

Comment: Examples here should help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have domain account, and both of those VMs are also part of domain then all you need to do is just to add that user by creating new login is SSMS.
(unfortunately I don't have enough "reputation" to add image to show, just google "how to create new login in sql server" and you should be able to find steps)

But if you don't have domain login or these VMs are not part of domain then I don't think you can use windows authentication.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question we really need more information like errors.

Firstly need to ensure your instance allows remote connections by configuring network protocols in SQL server configuration tool.

Also need to check if your connecting to a default instance or named..

If your still stuck post more information about your scenario.

Comment: added extra info...i'm still stuck